# MySQL Querying Duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a database called `teams`, and it currently looks like this:

```
team_id | leader_id | student_id
1       | 123456    | 1234
2       | 1234      | 123456, 1234567890
3       | 1234      | 123456
4       | 0         | 12345, 1234, 1234567890
5       | 0         |
6       | 0         |
```

My `students` database looks like this

```
student_id | first_name | last_name
123456     | qwer       | qwer
0          | asd        | zxc
1234567890 | mmm        |nnn
```

The user inputs a `leader_id`, and the user can input up to 7 `student_id`. The problem is that if the user inputs 1 `student_id`, everything is normal, but when the user inputs more than 1 `student_id`, than it stores the data more than once.

**Example:**

If the user enters `1234` as the `leader_id`, and enters `123456` and `1234567890` as the `student_id`, than it should store the data in one row, not separate the data into 2 rows.

Another thing is that in the last 3 rows, the user inputs 3 `student_id`, and the data gets stored in 1 row, but it adds 2 extra rows with nothing for the `student_id`

**My PHP**

```
<?php

    error_reporting(0);

    require '../../connect.php';

    $leader_id = $_POST['leader_id'];
    $student_id = array(
        $_POST['student_id_1'],
        $_POST['student_id_2'],
        $_POST['student_id_3'],
        $_POST['student_id_4'],
        $_POST['student_id_5'],
        $_POST['student_id_6']
    );

    $students_save = array();

    if(!empty($leader_id)) {

        foreach ($student_id as $id) {

            if(!empty($id)) {

                array_push($students_save, $id);

            }
        }

        foreach ($students_save as $save) {

            $check_id = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE student_id = $save");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($check_id)>0) {

                $students_save = implode(", ", $students_save);

                $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO teams (leader_id, student_id)
                    VALUES ('$leader_id', '$students_save');");

                    if($result) {

                        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Success!");

                    } else {

                        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Sorry we ran into an error");

                    }

            } else {

                header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=A Student ID Doesn't Exist");

            }

        }

    } else if(empty($leader_id)){

        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?Please add you're input values");

    }

 ?>
```

Comment: why would you want to store comma delimited values? that isn't compliant to a normalized database

Comment: I had to group the `student_id`'s together

Comment: Every team/leader/student relationship should exist in a separate _record_.  Why do you want to store CSV like this?

Comment: For each of the student_id, You are checking if the student exits or not in the database. & you are imploding the student id's in the same variable  $students_save. So it works well in the first iteration & not so in remaining iterations

Comment: Do you want to insert if anyone of student is existence or if only all the student id's exits?

Comment: I want to check if anyone of the students exists, than insert the data into `teams`

Comment: Sorry, Confused. You want to insert if atleast one of the student Id exists?

Comment: yes if anyone of the student id's exits.

Comment: As @Ghost said; you really should normalize your db. You're going to have a much harder time querying for any of MySQL's functions later on. It's not too late to turn back and start over if you're not too much into this. Have a read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization and continue your research on database normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you edited your question,**

> all you need is to break out of your foreach loop, if you $result is
>   successfull so add break in if($result) rest of the code will remain
>   the same

See the code below

```
    <?php

foreach ($students_save as $save) {

            $check_id = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE student_id = $save");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($check_id)>0) {

                $students_save = implode(", ", $students_save);

                $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO teams (leader_id, student_id)
                    VALUES ('$leader_id', '$students_save');");

                    if($result) {

                        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Success!");
                        break; // add break here, as if your condition      
                    } else {

                        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Sorry we ran into an error");

                    }

            } else {

                header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=A Student ID Doesn't Exist");

            }

        }
```

Comment: ok there are some other mistakes in your code, can you tell me why you are using, $save in your select query, than i will edit my answer, as it the moment it's not going to achieve the outcome which you want

Comment: in the `foreach` loop, `$save` is the value

Comment: i know that, and its for the student, but what the reason you are using it there, like you have to use it, for per student??

Comment: I'm checking if at least one of the `student_id` that the user inputs exists, if it exists, then I don't want to query the database

Comment: my `students` database doesn't have a `leader_id` column. I updated my code, so you can see my `students` table.

Comment: all you need is break; after inserting it, have look at the last portion of the solution

Comment: sorry sorry add the break after else, as i did not realize, in short where every you add the break; loop will break from, means it wont run, after that, so add after the else

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code if it helps,

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require '../../connect.php';

$leader_id = $_POST['leader_id'];
$student_id = array();
if(isset($_POST['student_id_1'])) $student_id[] = $_POST['student_id_1'];
if(isset($_POST['student_id_2'])) $student_id[] = $_POST['student_id_2'];
if(isset($_POST['student_id_3'])) $student_id[] = $_POST['student_id_3'];
if(isset($_POST['student_id_4'])) $student_id[] = $_POST['student_id_4'];
if(isset($_POST['student_id_5'])) $student_id[] = $_POST['student_id_5'];
if(isset($_POST['student_id_6'])) $student_id[] = $_POST['student_id_6'];

if(!empty($leader_id)) {
  $students_save = implode(", ", $student_id);
  $check_id = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE student_id IN ($students_save)");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($check_id)>0) {
    //$student_ids = array();
    //while($row = $check_id->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))  $student_ids[] = $row['student_id'];
    //$students_save = implode(", ", $student_ids);
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO teams (leader_id, student_id) VALUES ('$leader_id', '$students_save');");
    if($result) {
        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Success!");
    } else {
        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Sorry we ran into an error");
    }
  } else {
    header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=A Student ID Doesn't Exist");
  }
} else if(empty($leader_id)) {
  header("Location: ../../../admin.php?Please add you're input values");
}
?>
```

This code should help you.

**Note:** I have added comment to a part of the code. If you remove the commenting, then it will only insert the student_id which exists in the students table.

Comment: can you fix your code, its giving me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$student_id' (T_VARIABLE)` on `if(isset($_POST['student_id_1']) $student_id[] = $_POST['student_id_1'];
`

Comment: Now its returning `header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=A Student ID Doesn't Exist");`, instead of returning `header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Success!");`. Even when I put in the correct `student_id`

Comment: Sorry, doing it from my mobile. Fixed now

Comment: I will update the answer later in 3 hours if you still have issues.